# Posting Comment via Graph Api with symbols

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, symbols

hello is it possible to use symbols when posting comments via Graph api ?

If I try this symbols [image]

in a message.

it doesn't convert to symbols only shows the "text"

I'm using urlencode("My Message") when posting a comment.

Comment: When you try editing those texts manually, from Facebook page, what do you see?

Comment: manually these kind of symbols works without problems.

Comment: Try the message without `urlencode` as doing it changes `:)` to `%3A)`